# Declaring pending criminal prosecutions in a different country for home insurance purposes in the UK

Tags: criminal-law, united-kingdom, insurance

I am currently in the process of renewing my home insurance in the UK and most insurance providers require that you tell them whether or not you or someone in your household have any unspent convictions or pending prosecutions.

My partner who lives with me currently has an ongoing prosecution in the Republic of Ireland and I'd like to get some advice as to whether or not I need to declare this as it is in a different country?

As an example here is the statement from Churchill home insurance provider:

Have never been convicted of any criminal offence (other than motoring convictions) or have any prosecutions pending.

Comment: Does the question in the form specify "... in this country?". No. So the truthful answer is "yes, I have pending prosecution".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plain language clearly indicates that you would have to disclose this fact. There is nothing about the question that suggests that it is limited to a single country, and this applies with particular force since Brexit has not yet been effected.

Comment: Ah that's what I had thought but wanted to be certain. Thanks for your reply.